# Deploying Web App Manually on TomCat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a web app manually on Tomcat.
I have created a "myapp" folder in webapps folder with following files and folders:-

1)  myapp\WEB-INF\index.html

2) myapp\WEB-INF\classes

3) myapp\WEB-INF\lib

4) myapp\WEB-INF\myapp-servlet.xml

5) myapp\WEB-INF\web.html

But I am getting the following exception :-

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I linked my classes folder in tomcat and rest of the files I just copy pasted. I was able to run this like some time back. But I am not getting what i am missing. Is it build.xml? Thanks!

Update 1:-

```
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.089 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.093 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 6 2018 23:10:25 UTC
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.093 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.28.0
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.093 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_161-b12
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.094 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\conf\logging.properties
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.095 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:8000,server=y,suspend=n
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.096 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\temp
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
05-Mar-2018 16:18:51.097 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.219 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.442 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.801 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.826 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.831 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2489 ms
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
05-Mar-2018 16:18:52.890 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\docs]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:53.476 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\docs] has finished in [586] ms
05-Mar-2018 16:18:53.478 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\examples]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:54.474 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\examples] has finished in [997] ms
05-Mar-2018 16:18:54.475 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\host-manager]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:54.528 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [54] ms
05-Mar-2018 16:18:54.529 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\myapp]
05-Mar-2018 16:18:54.623 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5323bab5]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4868)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@3cbf78d5]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
    ... 17 more

05-Mar-2018 16:18:54.627 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\myapp]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Update 2:-
Adding POM.xml now I am getting following exception

```
05-Mar-2018 16:33:41.240 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name [myapp]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3155)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3145)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1375)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1189)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5113)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

05-Mar-2018 16:33:41.242 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [C:\Software Applications\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\myapp]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please, provide more logs from catalina.out(I assume you see this exception there). There might be something before this exception.

Comment: @SergeiSirik during tomcat startup

Comment: Yep, I've already figured out this from the exception you provided. Edited my first comment.

Comment: @SergeiSirik added logs

Comment: Deploy the war in web apps folder, tomcat will load it during the run, and it says Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name [myapp] check if you have any mapping errors.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi Thanks! I fixed it and posted as answer. Now all i need to do is hit the url in my spring controller. Now can you please tell me url format. my spring memory has got bit weak as i haven't worked on it for three years!

Comment: http://localhost:8080/myapp

Comment: yes but i checked my local host logs it show something  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet so i will fix it .Thanks!

Comment: How about you use a starter project or a guide quickly deploy and get a good feeling and then match the guide to what you are doing. It will be quick and smooth ;-)

Comment: yeah but why question has been downvoted its a good question some users do it just for fun i guess!

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi i guess this will help someone to put up their web app using eclipse classes did't found any url detailing this! if you have any starter guide then i can agree its bad question!

Comment: Okay, so what exactly are you trying to do? deploy app from eclipse to tomcat or debug your app in eclipse connecting to tomcat?

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi  am trying to create my own web app not deploy it! I guess i mentioned it in title of question

Comment: we can do screenshare may be use teamviewer

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi i can't do that i will fix it anyways..did you downvote the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166279/discussion-between-pranay-wankhede-and-vikram-palakurthi).

Comment: Nope, I did not downvote

Answer (score 0):

You can start by cheking if you are using jdk path for the runtime enviroments, you must use jre path. Make sure that tomcat uses the same java version as your application.

Comment: are you using a maven project ?

Comment: yes but i have included all dependencies in lib folder

Comment: why ? maven do that automatically. I need to see more logs. perhaps could be  two classes with the same name but different version.
You can try provided scoop :
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: adding pom.xml did the trick now the error has changed to something easy enough I will update it in question

Comment: Thanks for your help! now my web app is deployed how should i form my url?

Comment: But now i am not able to hit my controller and it gives me exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet even after adding all dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: even after having pom.xml i need to still add jars in lib and beacause of Spring-core jar i am getting same exception like illegal state exception

Comment: how do you do ? you use mvn clean install to get your .ear file ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answer I did following things :-

1) Added pom.xml instead of lib folder

2) Changed the servlet name in the web.xml

Deployed the above web app successfully on tomcat.

Update :
It's not pom.xml that makes tomcat fail but some jars that conflicts with tomcat lib on removing those everything is fine.